# php native function to return value based on key

Tags: php, arrays

The title can be a bit confusing, but how can you process an array and return the value of the key based on a value given. This is basically for an array library that converts database meta-data into human-readable format.

Example:

```
$countries = array('US'=>'United States','MX'=>'Mexico');
```

The above array would be considered an array library. So when I do a query and in my results I only have the two country code, I would then need to convert that into human-readable format. Is there a function that if I send it the two country code it will return the human-readable format. This function would then need to be reusable with other array libraries. Example function:

```
function covert_to_human($key, $array_library)
```

Comment: why not use use `$array_library[$key]`

Comment: what is the *'human-readable format'* you wish to return?

Comment: lol @Orangepill I didn't think of that. I guess I was overlooking at it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the value associated with $key in $array_library if it exists otherwise will return an optional $default if the key is not in the $array_library

```
function convert_to_human($key, $array_library, $default = null){
     if (array_key_exists($key, $array_library)){
           return $array_library[$key];
     }
     return $default;
}
```

If you want a supper easy way to define and maintain a lookup, you can wrap this concept in a class and use parse_ini_file to seed the data.

```
class Lookup{
     protected $data;

     public function __construct($iniFile){
          $this->data = parse_ini_file($iniFile);
     }

     public function lookup($key, $default){
          return isset($this->data[$key])?$this->data[$key]:$default;
     }
}
```

To use you would author your lookup as

```
; Countries.ini 
US = "United States of America"
MS = "Mexico"
CA = "Canada"
```

Then create an instance of and use your class

```
$countryLookup = new Lookup("Countries.ini");
echo $countryLookup->lookup("MX", "Unknown Country");
```

Comment: need to add a loop if he wants to send multiple $key values, which i think he deos

Answer (score 1):

```
function convert_to_human($key, $library) {
    return array_key_exists($key, $library) ? $library[$key] : false;
}
```